# Galera, tenho uma dúvida sobre a importação dessa biblioteca jquerry para poder aplicar uma máscara de cpf em determinada label

Tags: html, jquery, mask, jquery-masked-input

Tipo, na hora, o código não funciona, o script no caso, ai eu queria uma ajudinha de vocês pra entender se isso é um erro na hora que eu estou chamando a biblioteca e como proceder...

----html----

````
<html>
  <head>
    <script> scr="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.mask"</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>DATA</label>
          <input type="text" class="date">
          <label>HORAS</label>
          <input type="text" class="time">
          <label>CEP</label>
          <input type="text" class="cep">
          <label>TELEFONE</label>
          <input type="text" class="phone">
          <label>CPF</label>
          <input type="text" class="cpf">
          <label>DINHEIRO</label>
          <input type="text" class="money">
  </body>
  

</html>```

----script----
```$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').mask('00/00/0000')
    $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
    $('.cep').mask('00000-000');
    $('.phone').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
    $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
    $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000,00');
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa primeiro incluir no seu HTML o JQuery. O link do Jquery Mask está errado.
O seu código com estes dois scripts atualizados ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label>DATA</label>
          <input type="text" class="date">
          <label>HORAS</label>
          <input type="text" class="time">
          <label>CEP</label>
          <input type="text" class="cep">
          <label>TELEFONE</label>
          <input type="text" class="phone">
          <label>CPF</label>
          <input type="text" class="cpf">
          <label>DINHEIRO</label>
          <input type="text" class="money">
  </body>
  

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').mask('00/00/0000')
    $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
    $('.cep').mask('00000-000');
    $('.phone').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
    $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
    $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000,00');
});
</script>
```

Comment: amigão esse ```integrity``` é tipo, realmente necessário ? vi em outros exemplos que ele num era tão necessário e já que você colocou ele na correção do meu código, queria entender mais a importância dele